# ran out of vram while creating opengles1.1 texture view

Tags: android, android-ndk, textures, opengl-es-1.1, textureview

I used the below code from the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/U5RXFGpAHPE) to create the `opengles1.1` texture-view .

My app has like a view which few buttons with 3D models names if user clicks the 
button a new texture view is created.

If back is clicked user will be back the texture view is deleted.

Now the problem is after doing this for 5 to 6 times, the app crashes with following errors:

```
E/IMGSRV  (18294): :0: PVRSRVAllocDeviceMem: Error 1 returned
E/IMGSRV  (18294): :0: UCH_CodeHeapCreate: Out of device mem
E/IMGSRV  (18294): :0: CreateSharedState: Failed to create USSE vertex code heap!
E/IMGSRV  (18294):
E/IMGSRV  (18294): :0: InitContext: CreateSharedState failed
E/IMGSRV  (18294): :0: GLESCreateGC: Failed to init the gc
E/libEGL  (18294): eglMakeCurrent:552 error 3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/dalvikvm(18294): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41218930)
E/AndroidRuntime(18294): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1895
E/AndroidRuntime(18294): java.lang.RuntimeException: eglMakeCurrent failed EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

Can anyone please help me on this what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're leaking EGL contexts?  If you're creating and destroying your own contexts, add some logs or trace through it with a debugger to make sure it's working right.

Comment: eglDestroyContext,eglDestroySurface,eglTerminate are getting called is there any thing else i need to do ??

Comment: Contexts and Surfaces aren't actually destroyed until they're no longer current, so it's good to do an `eglMakeCurrent()` with NO_CONTEXT and NO_SURFACE.  This should only be a problem if you're creating a separate thread for rendering -- otherwise they should be getting cleaned up when the next context+surface is made current.

Comment: i had done that "eglMakeCurrent() with NO_CONTEXT and NO_SURFACE" before calling eglDestroyContext,eglDestroySurface,eglTerminate but still this is happening